# Calculating the magnitude and phase angle of a transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, homework

How do I find the magnitude and phase angle of this transfer function?

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{(j\omega+6)^2}$$

Comment: Please show your attempt

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a homework problem but I will show you how to obtain these results. After all, what is important is that you learn how to do it for the next round :-) One option consists of expanding your expression and rearranging it to separate the real and imaginary terms. Then, you apply the magnitude and argument definitions of a complex number to extract the results you want. This is the right part of the below figure:

[image]

I personally prefer to deal directly with poles and zeroes rather than with complex numbers. I have thus rearranged your original transfer function in a so-called *low-entropy* format where you immediately see a gain at dc and a pole located at 0.95 Hz. From this expression, I can derive the magnitude and phase expression straight away, without manipulating complex numbers and it is simpler in my opinion. The below picture shows that all results are rigorously identical when graphed with Mathcad:

[image]

You can apply whatever method you want but, in the end, it is important that the obtained expressions bring insight when looking at them. As an engineer, you run analysis exercises not for the beauty of them but to fulfill a goal which is designing a working circuit. This is what is called *design-oriented analysis* or D-OA, a term forged by [Dr. Middlebrook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._D._Middlebrook) many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the amplitude, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)^2}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|1\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)^2\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left(\left|6+\text{j}\omega\right|\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left(\sqrt{6^2+\omega^2}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle36+\omega^2}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

And for the argument:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)&=\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)^2}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(1\right)-\arg\left(\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)^2\right)\\
\\
&=0-\arg\left(\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)\right)\\
\\
&=-\left(\arg\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)+\arg\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)\right)\\
\\
&=-\left(2\arg\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)\right)\\
\\
&=-2\arg\left(6+\text{j}\omega\right)\\
\\
&=-2\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\omega}{\displaystyle6}\right)
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}